# Keep the colors of the textView text after appending NSSting

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsmutableattributedstring

I'm using the next method to change the colors of few words in textView:

```
+(void)changeColorToTextObject : (UITextView *)textView ToColor : (UIColor *)color FromLocation : (int)location length : (int)length
{
    NSMutableAttributedString *text = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString: textView.attributedText];

    [text addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:color range:NSMakeRange(location, length)];
    [textView setAttributedText: text];
}
```

and it looks like this:
[image]

but when i'm adding new value to this text the color are gone.

`myTextView.text = [myTextView.text stringByAppendingString:newStr];`

And it looks like this:

[image]

How can I keep the colors like before with the new string?

Comment: I edited my answer, now the code should work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `myTextView.text = [myTextView.text stringByAppendingString:newStr];` use:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *text = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:myTextView.attributedText];
NSAttributedString *newAttrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:newStr];
[text appendAttributedString:newAttrString];
myTextView.attributedText = text;
```

Your code does not work because you are assigning to a new string to the `text` property of `myTextView`. `text` is just just a `NSString` property and thus is not able to display colors or other things that can be displayed using an `NSAttributedString`.

Note that writing `myTextView.attributedText = text;` calls the *setter* of the *property* `attributedText` and thus is 100% equivalent to `[myTextView setAttributedText:text];`, just a different notation.

Comment: For some reason the append method is crushing the app.

I tried the code:
    NSMutableAttributedString *text = (NSMutableAttributedString *)myTextView.attributedText;
    NSAttributedString *str = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:newStr];
    [text appendAttributedString:str];
    myTextView.attributedText = text;

Comment: are you getting an error message? make sure that `newString` is _not_ `nil` in any case :)

Comment: Yes i'm sure :) there is value in the str

Comment: ah sorry, there was a glitch in my code!! you need to use use `[text appendAttributedString:newAttrString];` instead of `[text appendAttributedString:newString];`